# How can I install a database in a titanium alloy project?

Tags: sqlite, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have been trying to install a tiny simple database into my titanium project with the code from the documentation and trying different tweaks as suggested by a variety of sources.  But I cannot get it to work, I get errors like "no such table" or resultset is null.  Currenty my code looks like this:

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('../assets/exercises.db', 'exercisesDB');
Ti.API.info('installed '+ db.getName()  );
db.close();
Ti.API.info('closed db'  );
db = Ti.Database.open('exercisesDB');
Ti.API.info('reopened db'  );
//Ti.API.info(db.getName()  );
var exercisesDBRS = db.execute('SELECT id,name FROM exercise');
```

I have tried putting the database file exercises.db in the assets folder and in the Resources folder but I'm getting no where.  I created the db file with "DB Browser for SQLite" ver 3.9.1 on OSX Sierra -  is it compatible with appcelerator alloy projects?  My current code produces the error "no such table" on the execute call.  I assure you the db file has an exercise table.

PS, full code in new projects index.js file is as follow:

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('exercises.sqlite', 'exercisesDB');
Ti.API.debug('installed '+ db.getName()  );
db.close();
Ti.API.debug('closed db'  );
db = Ti.Database.open('exercisesDB');
Ti.API.debug('reopened db'  );
var exercisesDBRS = db.execute('SELECT id, name FROM exercise');
Ti.API.debug('executed select');
Ti.API.debug(' rowcount== '+   exercisesDBRS.rowCount);

while (exercisesDBRS.isValidRow()) {
    var exId = exercisesDBRS.fieldByName('id');
    var exName = exercisesDBRS.fieldByName('name');

    Ti.API.debug("Exercise: "+exId + ' ' + exName  );
    exercisesDBRS.next();
}
exercisesDBRS.close();
db.close(); 

function doClick(e) {
    alert($.label.text);
}

$.index.open();
```

New project but same code and a copy of the same database file in the app/lib folder.  Same error - no such table on the execute line when tested in android, works fine in iOS sim.

Answer (score 3):

As per the docs, your external database should be located at the same place where you are running the below code:

`var db = Ti.Database.install('../assets/exercises.db', 'exercisesDB');`

1. There's no need to use ***../assets/***. You can simply refer the database without it because everything you put in assets folder is moved to respective **Resources->iphone/android** folder.
2. You can always use **Ti.Database.install** method for external database because after installing a database once, it will behave like **Ti.Database.open('exercisesDB')** method.

Coming to your primary concern, you can always safely put your database file in ***app -> lib*** folder (create ***lib*** folder if it's not present and put db file in there then).

After putting the db file there, you can always use below code:

`var db = Ti.Database.install('exercises.db', 'exercisesDB');`

Though, I have never used **.db extension**, instead I have always used **.sqlite format** (since docs also says SQLite database) and it has worked 100% correct every time.

So you can try this process by changing the database format to **.sqlite** and put it in **app->lib** folder. It will definitely work and after verifying you can use same code on using a **.db** file and see if it's supported or not.

***On Android: Follow these steps:***

**1-** In your PC, go to the project's root directory, delete **build** and **Resources** folders.

**2-** On device, clear app data from Settings and then delete the app.

**3-** Now install the app again with the same code and flow as I mentioned here.

If it's working fine for iOS sim, then it should also work for Android (only some cleaning issues are there or your previous database is still there).

Comment: Thanks but I tried the lib folder  and the script folder but get the same error.   Tried it with and without the "/", same error.  BTW, I can create the table with sql and then run the query without error but of course also without any rows returned.

Comment: BTW, I also tried the full absolute path to the db file,  which I tried as both a .db and .sqlite.  No luck so far.

Comment: Some progress, after cleaning the project and removing the app from the iOS simulator it worked.  However the same process did not work on my android device, still getting the same no such table error.  i'm guessing the old database is still hanging around on the device.  Tried clearing app data but still no luck.

Comment: Even on a fresh android emulator it gives the same error.  I retried the install command without the full path like you said and now it seems to work in the iOS sim, but I'm still getting nowhere on android.

Comment: I have edited my answer by adding some steps to run the app on Android properly.

Comment: Then only option is to see your code. Send your project's folder (excluding build & Resources folders) @ **prashant10103497@gmail.com**

Comment: There is nothing to see except what I showed as  the app is in the very early stages.  That code is the first code to run in the app and it crashes the app.  What application do you use to create your sqlite files?

Comment: **DB Browser for SQLite** and I type in extension as .sqlite after selecting All Files in format drop-down.

Comment: Tried that too,  still no luck.  I think I am going to give up on appcelerator, this one is just the latest in a  long line of problems I have experienced with it.  Usually weird things that have little to do with coding but poor documentation or bugs in the tools.   Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Do one last thing: Email me your whole app on that email address. There's nothing wrong with Appcelerator, rather it's some minute thing missing in your code.

Comment: I just created a new alloy project with nothing but that code ( without the "../assets/" and with the db file in the /app/lib folder ) in the index.js file.   Exact same error on Android device.  Worked perfect on iOS sim. Updating question to show full code of the index.js file.

Comment: Did you uninstall the app before trying again? I just tried your code by creating exercises.sqlite file and putting some data in it and it worked fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134356/discussion-between-prashant-saini-and-lost-baby).